# Is there a dependency manager for VC++?

Tags: c#, c++, dependency-management

Our organization has lots of C# and C++ code that we have to integrate. With C#, NuGet is a great option because it manages the build process by adding/updating references in the project files. Is there something similar for Visual C++ that can manage the dependencies between C++ projects? Also, is there something that integrates dependencies between C# and C++?

Comment: No.  The C++ tool chain is missing the kind of metadata that's required to discover dependencies.  Its lack for reflection support being the biggest hangup.

Comment: I don't believe NuGet uses reflection. It just uses `packages.xml` files and the `*.csproj` files to track dependencies. I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

www.cppdepend.com/, cppdepend can analyze the project dependencies in VC ++,,  it is not free. It has a trial version, you can check it out

Comment: This sounds a lot like [understand](http://scitools.com/?gclid=CIX75-KMwbMCFe5FMgodw14A2A). They're all great tools and have their place, but I'm looking for something that manages modules, not just classes and methods. It's primary purpose isn't visualization, but management of internal packages. Some people call them artifact repositories.